# How to post message from parent to child iframe without window.postMessage?

Tags: iframe, postmessage

I have an app that has an iframe from the same origin.
i want to send data from parent to child iframe. Because the iframe is from the same domain(same origin), i don't want to use window.postMessage as it is used for cross origin requests.

Is there a way other than postMessage to send data to child iframe.